# How to make a variable available to all gRPC request handlers on a gRPC server?

Tags: go, grpc

I'm starting my gRPC server like this:

```
func Run(...) ... {
    // this is variable I want to add to all my request handler's context
    foo := "bar"

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    grpc_health_v1.RegisterHealthServer(grpcServer, health.NewServer())
    pb.RegisterMyServer(grpcServer, newServer())
    signal.Notify(sigChan, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGINT)

    go func() {
        if err := grpcServer.Serve(lis); err != nil {
            errChan <- err
        }
    }()

    return grpcServer, nil
}
```

And here's an example of a handler for a "ping" request:

```
func (s *myServer) Ping(
    ctx context.Context,
    pingRequest *pb.PingRequest,
) (*pb.PingResponse, error) {
    return &pb.PingResponse{}, nil
}
```

You can see in `Run()` that I have a variable `foo` that I would somehow like to be available to all my request handlers. This variable does not depend on the client's request in any way, it just needs to be available in the request handlers.

What is the best way to achieve this?

- Use a singleton
- Use a global
- Somehow add it to the gRPC request contexts?

Comment: Use it as a property field in myServer

Comment: @nipuna could you share an example? `MyServer` is generated by protoc in this case, so not sure how I would define that in a `.proto`

Answer (score 2):

Use your custom implementation to GRPC server.

```
type GrpcServer struct {
    Foo string
}

func (g *GrpcServer) Ping(ctx context.Context, pingRequest *pb.PingRequest, ) (*pb.PingResponse, error) {
    fmt.Println(g.Foo)
    return &pb.PingResponse{}, nil
}
```

And register your custom implementation of grpc server.

```
func Run() {
    
    foo := "bar"

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    grpc_health_v1.RegisterHealthServer(grpcServer, health.NewServer())
    pb.RegisterMyServer(grpcServer, &GrpcServer{Foo: foo})
    signal.Notify(sigChan, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGINT)

    go func() {
        if err := grpcServer.Serve(lis); err != nil {
            errChan <- err
        }
    }()

    return grpcServer, nil
}
```

Comment: and what about `MyServer` struct? Isnt it needed? I would also embed the `MyServer` into `GrcpServer`

Comment: it is not needed. Implement this and test the code to make sure

Comment: no i mean the code that he showed us is not a real implementation. What if some fields from `MyServer` are needed when processing request?

Comment: Then inject it as well. I don't know about your `newServer` function. So do the needful for that